# How to declare a static array of vectors?

Tags: rust

How would one go about declaring a static/constant array of variable-sized arrays (vectors) in Rust? In C++ you could do something like this:

```
static const std::vector<std::string> MY_STRINGS[] = {
    { "hi" },
    { "hello", "world" },
    { "salutations", "watery", "globe" }
};
```

and things would work as you expect (the array is constructed during app launch afaik). What's the equivalent code in Rust? Seems like the compiler is trying its very best to prevent me from doing this.

Comment: You need to include some Rust code showing what you have tried and the errors you are getting. And how are you intending to use it? That will affect how it can be done.

Comment: Can they be fixed size arrays, or do you plan to add/remove strings at runtime?

Comment: The size and content of everything is known at compile time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`once_cell::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.Lazy.html#) `sync` or `unsync` variants depending on your needs:

```rust
const MY_STR: Lazy<[Vec<&str>; 2]> =
    Lazy::new(|| [vec!["hi"], vec!["hello", "world"]]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e738e95f82b56d090be370c7105796df)

It is still in nightly but this functionality will hit stable at some point. [`std::lazy::Lazy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/struct.Lazy.html) and [`std::lazy::SyncLazy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/struct.SyncLazy.html).

Comment: Note that `std::lazy::Lazy` is thread unsafe (equivalent to `once_cell::unsync::Lazy`). There is [`std::lazy::SyncLazy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/struct.SyncLazy.html) for thread-safe access.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, yep nice point in clarifying that. Feel free to edit the answer and add that point. Thanks!

Comment: but, collect to array not allowed, still need a long literal code...

Comment: @JiangYD, it is allowed for sure. Maybe you missing some type signature.

Comment: @Netwave `let v:[Vec<u32>;2] = [1u32,2u32].iter().map(|x|vec![v]).collect();` will this work?

Comment: @JiangYD, you need to collect into a `Vec` and then `try_into` + `unwrap`, all inside the Lazy stuff if `const`, but yest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on *nightly*, you can use [`LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html). Like this:

```
#![feature(once_cell)]   // 1.65.0-nightly

use std::sync::LazyLock;

const MY_STRINGS: LazyLock<[Vec<&str>; 3]> =
    LazyLock::new(|| [
        vec!["hi"], 
        vec!["hello", "world"],
        vec!["salutations", "watery", "globe"]
    ]);

fn main() {
    println!("{}, {}", MY_STRINGS[1][0], MY_STRINGS[2][2]);
}
```

`LazyLock` more or less does what the crates [once_cell](https://crates.io/crates/once_cell) and [lazy_sync](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) do. Those two crates are very common, so there's a good chance they might already by in your `Cargo.lock` dependency tree. But if you prefer to be a bit more "adventurous" and go with `LazyLock`, be prepered that it (as everything in *nightly*) might be a subject to change before it gets to *stable*.

(Note: Up until recently `std::sync::LazyLock` used to be named `std::lazy::SyncLazy` but was recently [renamed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/98165).)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot have 'const' items with destructors, so `Vec` is not allowed.

If you know the size of the "vec" at compile time, you can use an array:

```rust
const MY_STRS: [&'static str; 3] = [
  "first",
  "second",
  "third"
];
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest looking at the `lazy_static` crate: https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static

This lets you write something like the following:

```rust
lazy_static! {
  static ref MY_STRS: Vec<String> = {
    let mut strings = vec![];
    strings.push("hello".to_string());
    strings
  }
}
```

This behaves as the name suggests; it is lazily initialized when first accessed.

I'd recommend reading the docs for this crate to get an understanding of the thread-safety implications